# Send push notification to people within a x-meter radius with OneSignal

Tags: vue.js, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, onesignal

I have a **OneSignal** account.
I have a front-end PWA built with VueJs that collects users & sends there location in a tag.

```
  OneSignal.push(function() {
    OneSignal.sendTags({
      latitude: latitude,
      long: longitude
    })
  })
```

I have successfully sent push messages from the API, when addressing all or a specific segment.
My problem is when using the **location** filter.

I have tried with this Json :

```
{"app_id": "APIKEY","contents": {"en": "English Message"},"filters": [{"field": "location", "radius": "1000", "lat": "50.747164", "long": "3.345545"}]}
```

I realise it's counter intuitive to send latitude and expect to filter on lat... but this is what i found in the documentation. Also some things made me think 'location' is a field of its own, not part of the tag. But I could not find this field when creating a segment manualy. So I've hit a dead end here.

If I should use a different platform, or a whole different approach, I'm open to that. Currently I'm stuck with no extra info.

Answer (score 1):

**register for native devices** on OneSignal.

If this is happening to you you are possibly not registered on native platforms.
Check in your One-signal under settings if you have registered native devices.

Location based sending only works with native device setup.
If 'location' is not under segment then it is just not active.